# Subsetting a vector with a logical condition

Tags: r

```
> x1=c(4,5,6,7,8)
> x1
[1] 4 5 6 7 8
> x2=x1[x1!=6]
> x2
[1] 4 5 7 8
> x3=x1[x1=6]
> x3
[1] NA
```

Why is `x3` not 6? I don't understand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<-` and `=` are assignment operators. By using `x1[x1=6]`, you are assigning the value of `6` to `x1`, not checking whether they match. Type in  `?assignOps` at the R prompt for more info. Use `==` instead.

```
x3 <- x1[x1==6]
```